# Why doesn't the bootable USB show up in the BIOS?

Tags: 12.04, boot, system-installation, usb, usb-drive

I followed all the instructions on the Ubuntu website as to how to install Ubuntu using a bootable USB. I got the linux pendrive thing, formatted the USB, and have nothing on it besides what was put there by the pendrive program. I'm on a toshiba satellite, Windows 7. When I restart the pc, I hit F2 for the Bios and it's just not there. I booted it up with anything I possibly could but none of them were the usb stick, so none of them showed the Ubuntu installation screen. After going back and scavenging to find something I may have done wrong, then re-doing it, it's still not working. The drive itself is some form of 8gb Lexar, if that helps anything.

Comment: Look in your BIOS, and see if legacy USB is enabled.  Plus what is the exact model of your laptop?

Comment: toshiba satellite l455d-s5976

Comment: some old computers do not provide the facility of usb booting. you need to specify the configuration of your computer.

Answer (score 2):

try disabling secure boot from boot option menu and choose the boot method from Legacy boot menu as usb drive from there.
there may be some option other than F2 in boot screen to enter Legacy boot option menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a couple more attempts in addition to those already proposed there are two things to verify:

- The hashsum of the ISO that you've used to prepare the USB match with the website's hash?
- If you already have a Linux OS installed you can made a check with gParted of the flags: Open gParted, select the USB Stick, the partition need to have a `bootable` flag. If it doesn't have this flag something went wrong with ISO burning..

Answer (score 0):

usually the problem may be in your flashdrive or your pc can't bootup from liveusb (most old computers can't do that)

I have a flashdrive which is not working on all computers, try to burnd a dvd or change flashdrive, and check if you have boot menu

Answer (score 0):

Rodislav answer will work, most probably the problem is with your flash drive, change flash drive with 4GB capacity. Normally older computers not recognizing higher capacity flash drive. To enter into bios set up hit F2 or F8 or F12 or ESC depending on your computer configuration.